# How does '/' in javascript works?

Tags: javascript, regex

How this is possible?

```
var re = /\w+/;
```

I have never seen something like this in any other language. Is this part of language sintax or something else? Leading '/' is what I don't understand, what exactly js does when it gets that with the "\w+/"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a regular expression literal.

[**From the MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

> You construct a regular expression in one of two ways:
>
> Using a regular expression literal, as follows:
>
> ```
> var re = /ab+c/;
> ```
>
> Regular expression literals provide compilation of
>   the regular expression when the script is evaluated. When the regular
>   expression will remain constant, use this for better performance.
>
> Calling the constructor function of the RegExp object, as follows: 1
>
> ```
> var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
> ```
>
> Using the constructor function provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

Comment: Might be worth adding the benefits of using the `new RegExp()` for, among other things, matching strings represented by a variable (which can't, so far as I know, be done using regex literals). Also that using `new RegExp()` requires escaping/double-escaping of characters. But I'm perhaps being fussy. ...sorry.

Comment: `/myRegex/.match(myVar)`? @DavidThomas **EDIT:** Oops, the other way around: `myVar.match(/myRegex/);`.

Comment: @11684: was thinking more of using a variable *within* the regular expression, not trying to *find* the string represented by the variable *in* the expression. I may have phrased it *very, very* badly though. Apparently I was referring to 'runtime compilation of the regular expression,' so I *did*, in fact, phrase it *very* badly. Oops.

Comment: Ah. Is that really impossible? If only one language would have supported this, I would have expected Javascript to be that. @DavidThomas

Comment: @11684: I've not really *tried*, I just recall seeing many questions here asking how to build regular expressions in functions using variables, and all the answers suggest that it's impossible using RegEx literals, and answer with using the RegEx constructor. So, I'm convinced that it's not possible, but I've not undertaken any actual research.

Comment: As the text above says, you need to use the constructor function to build the dynamic reg exp.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

It's about the same as using the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor to build your regular expression but it's immediately compiled when parsed and you don't need to escape `\`.

Note that you have the same syntactic structure in at least another language : Perl.

Answer (score 0):

its not JavaScript-exclusive, its [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), or RegEx. The '/' starts and ends the expression that you are comparing something against.

Comment: Of course that slash is JavaScript, how else would the JS interpreter what it is? It throws no error.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not JavaScript"?

Comment: RegEx is use in WAY more languages than JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, but the slash - and the question IS about that slash - is definitely JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah i changed my answer to be a bit more specific. Apologies for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

That is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). It defines a rule for matching strings and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It isRegular expressions; which are used to perform pattern-matching and "search-and-replace" functions on text.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's RegExp syntax that is part of the Javascript standard and is completely normal to use.

`/\w+/` in RegExp means to look for alphanumeric characters in sequence...   `\w` represents any letter or number in the alpha bet. `+` means that there should be at least 1 or more in a sequence.

```
"this123 is a test".match(/\w+/) == "this123"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of poetry: *`/` is to regexps as `"` is to strings.*

```js
var intVar = 0;
var stringVar = "0";
var regexpVar = /0/;
```